# How to record video from an Android phone directly to a cloud?

Tags: remote-control, video-recording, cloud, video-streaming

Perilous times...

I have to be able to record/stream a video through my Android, just like anyone does to its local storage, but instead, directly to a file somewhere on the cloud. What's most important to me is, if while recording a video the recording stops, there's a guarantee that's what's been recorded till the last seconds is already in the cloud, and is a playable file.

Realtime playable streaming is not essential. I want to make sure that while I'm recording a video I know that most of the video is already on the cloud, and the video extends while the Android phone is in the recording state.

What are the solutions to this?

Ideally, I want to be able to record to a shared directory on the google drive.

Comment: Maybe something like YouTube/Facebook live? Never tried it, but I'd imagine that you are able to record privately and even if the video stops, what has been recorded will be saved.

Comment: as for YouTube Live, there's currently a requirement for at least 1000 subs to have to be able to live stream on mobile

Comment: Ok what about some security camera app that uses the phone camera? Dunno about the quality, but still might be a possiblity